# Asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{(k!)^\nu}$

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

Let $\nu>0$ be fixed.  I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the series
\begin{equation*}s(n,\nu)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{(k!)^\nu}
\end{equation*}
in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.  For integer $\nu\geq2$, it was shown by Shmueli et al. 2005 that $s(n,\nu)$ can be represented as the multiple integral
\begin{equation*}s(n,\nu)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\nu-1}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\!\cdots\!\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\bigg\{n^{1/\nu}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\nu-1}\exp(ib_k)+\exp\bigg(-\sum_{k=1}^{\nu-1}ib_k\bigg)\bigg)\bigg\}\,db_1\ldots\,db_{v-1},
\end{equation*}
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  A standard application of Laplace's approximation for multiple integrals then yields the asymptotic formula
\begin{equation*}s(n,\nu)\sim \frac{\exp(\nu n^{1/\nu})}{n^{(\nu-1)/2\nu}(2\pi)^{(\nu-1)/2}\sqrt{\nu}}(1+O(n^{-1/\nu})) \quad \mbox{as}\: n\rightarrow\infty,
\end{equation*}
where $\nu\geq2$ is an integer.

I would like to obtain a similar asymptotic formula for $s(n,\nu)$ for any positive real $\nu$.   I have reasons to believe that the above asymptotic formula is valid for all $\nu>0$, although I can't think of an approach that would yield such a result.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a complete reference for the Shmueli paper?

Comment: http://www.galitshmueli.com/system/files/JRSS-COM-Poisson.pdf

Comment: @AntonioVargas. This link seems to be outdated. Do you remember the paper by any chance?

Comment: @bob I'm pretty sure it's this one https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2005.00474.x That multiple integral is eqn. 40 in that paper.

Comment: @bob looks like the derivation is also sketched in this note https://www.stat.cmu.edu/tr/tr776/tr776.pdf

Comment: @AntonioVargas. Thank you. I'll take a look.